# Jersey 2.25 and Tomcat 9.0.33 always responding 404 Not found

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I have been searching for so many days and I can't find any solution or where is the problem so please don't mark the question as repeated because it's really not. I read all the questions and the answers, I tried all the solutions and still not working.

I am using Intellij, Jersey 2.25 and Tomcat 9.0.33. I am not allowed to use maven so I download all the jar dependencies manually and then reference them from the project structure window by adding them to the libraries and artifacts.
The server is deployed successfully and when I open http://localhost:8080/ofar_war_exploded/ it shows the content of the index.jsp file. However, when I try to access a resource for example a simple method that returns a string in my OptimizerResource class I get the following response

*HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.33*

The lib folder contains all the dependencies needed. I tried to add also the lib folder inside WEB-INF I got the same behavior.
[This is the list of all the jars I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwoE3.png)

This is the content of the web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <display-name>Optimizer Service</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>optimizer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest.resources</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>optimizer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Just for a testing wise I added only one get method in the OptimizerResource class that returns hello. When I try to request this url http://localhost:8080/ofar_war_exploded/rest/optimizer/hello
I receive 404 not found.

```
@Path("optimizer")
public class OptimizerResource {
  @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your jars need to be in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I already tried to run it with the jar files in WEB-INF/lib. It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a mistake in the dependencies, they were incorrect.
The working set of dependencies are as follow:
[List of Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMWNM.png)

The List of all jersey bundles with complete dependencies
[Link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/)

Or you can download jersey download the full dependencies bundle from this [Link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/bundles/jaxrs-ri/2.26/jaxrs-ri-2.26.zip)